# Why is $.isnumeric false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing some JavaScript and I have a table where I need to test a field for either a database key ( a number ), or a the default value ("NO MATCH"). I'm trying to use the jQuery function 'isNumeric'

The code is :

```
var id = $('#myDataTable input:checked').map(function(){
     return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();
}).get();

console.log(" ID "+id);
console.log(" ID2 "+$.isNumeric(id));
```

In my console, I see:

```
ID 1
ID2 false
```

Why is this not true?

Comment: `.get()` return you an array, try with `id[0]`

Comment: try trim string first

Comment: When you debug never concatenate your variables with strings! If you used `console.log("ID", id);` you would have seen `["1"]` instead of `"1"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.get()` returns the array `["1"]`, which is non-numeric.

When you log it to the console you can't see that because you concatenate it with a string, and `["1"].toString()` is `"1"`.

Instead, when you debug it's better to avoid coercing your variables to other types. `console.log("ID", id)` would be better.

To get the string instead of the array, you can use `.get(0)` or `[0]`.

However, if you are only interested in the first string, there is no point in using `map`:

```
var id = $('#myDataTable input:checked').eq(0)
         .closest('tr').find('td').eq(3)
         .text();
```